# Django forms: i cant access the forms from the home page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

When I click the login or signup buttons on the main page, it goes to the links but the forms are not coming. Pages are coming empty. No errors appear in console. When i remove the part {% extends "base_generic.html" %} from login.html , then i access the login page successfuly.I can't find out where I made a mistake. Thanks for your help. Sorry for my bad English.

```
    #models.py

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)


class Student(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    student_no = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=9, help_text="student number")
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="student name")
    student_surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="student surname")

    class Meta:
        permissions = (("can_upload_photo", "Upload Photo Permission"),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_no


# views.py
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = MyUser
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'student'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('index.html')


#forms.py
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = MyUser

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        return user

#urls.py
urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/student/', views.StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='student_signup'),
    path('accounts/signup/teacher/', views.TeacherSignUpView.as_view(), name='teacher_signup'),
]


#base_generic.html
            <div class="col-6 text-right">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p class="pt-3">Logged in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>. <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>.</p>
              {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-light" role="button">Log in</a>
                <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Sign up</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>


#login.html
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
      <h2>Log in</h2>
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.password }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}


#signup.html
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up for a free account</h2>
  <p class="lead">Select below the type of account you want to create</p>
  <a href="{% url 'student_signup' %}" class="btn btn-student btn-lg" role="button">I'm a student</a>
  <a href="{% url 'teacher_signup' %}" class="btn btn-teacher btn-lg" role="button">I'm a teacher</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does your base_generic.html file include the `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` tags?

Comment: there are no tags `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}`  in the base_generic.html

Comment: oh :D i found my mistake. Thank you @MattRowbum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` tags in your base_generic.html file.

When you "extend" the base template, these tags indicate where the extra content should be inserted.

See [Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#id1)